# function for each element in an array is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a shopping cart that is being populated through local storage data.

```
var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    var id = cartarry[i].id;

    var name = cartarry[i].name;
    var price = cartarry[i].price.replace('$', "")
    var quantity = cartarry[i].quantity;

    var itemcontainer = document.getElementById('myContent');
    var itemcard = `
      <div>
          <div>
            <div>Dingo Dog Bones</div>
            <p>${name}</p>
          </div>
          <div>${price}</div>
          <div><input min="1" type="number" value="${quantity}" /></div>
          <div><button> Remove </button></div>
          <div>25.98</div>
      </div>
                 `;

    itemcontainer.innerHTML += itemcard;
    calculatelinetotal()
}
```

this is my calculatelinetotal() function

```
function calculatelinetotal() {
    var price1 = document.getElementById('productprice').innerHTML;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('productquantity').value;

    var price = price1.replace('$', '')
    var total = parseInt(price * quantity);

    document.getElementById('productlineprice').innerHTML = total;
}
```

the problem with this is that it only calculates the price total for the first product and not for every product.
this is the output

[image]

what am I doing wrongly and how can I get it to dynamically calculate the total for each line and cart total.

Comment: in valid HTML, id's **must be unique** - how do you expect your code to know which `productprice` you mean, for example? javascript has no foreknowledge of your intent

Comment: You keep writing to the same DOM element.

Comment: can you console.log(arrayLength) and tell me what you are getting on your console

Comment: Do you really need `calculatelinetotal` given that you already have `price` and `quantity`? You could just calculate them (`price * quantity`) and set the value in `product-line-price` right away the same way you are doing with `id`, `name`, `price` and `quantity`.

Comment: @mersocarlin you are right ! it also provides intantaneous recalculation when the quantity is changed. Amazing

Comment: @learner101 no problem :) I just posted my comment as an answer so we can help others that eventually have the same problem as you had :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating and parsing string without the need to do so.
Not to mention that it also affects performance in your application.

My suggestion is to follow the same approach you are using with `id`, `name`, `price` and `quantity` so you calculate each item's total right away (you actually don't need `calculatelinetotal`)

```
var price = parseInt(cartarry[i].price.replace('$',""))
var quantity = parseInt(cartarry[i].quantity);

const total = price * quantity

const item card = `
  <div class="product" id="${id}">
    <div class="product-details">
    <div class="product-title">Dingo Dog Bones</div>
    <p class="product-description"> ${name}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-price" id='productprice'>${price}</div>
    <div class="product-quantity">
    <input type="number" id='productquantity' value=${quantity} min="1">
  </div>
  <div class="product-removal">
  <button class="remove-product"> Remove </button>
  </div>
  <div class="product-line-price">{total}</div>
  </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing you are doing wrong that you are using `itemcontainer.innerHTML += itemcard;` in your for loop you just need to first make an object of your html in for loop `conatiner += itemcard;` then you have to use conatiner object outside  for loop like this `itemcontainer.innerHTML = conatiner;`

Because after for loop end then you have a full object that you can insert into your DOM, now it will only show you only one result.

Answer (score 0):

your html should not contain dublicated IDs they should be unique, first let's move ids to be classes:

```
var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    var id = cartarry[i].id;
    var name = cartarry[i].name;
    var price = cartarry[i].price.replace('$',"")
    var quantity = cartarry[i].quantity;

    var itemcontainer = document.getElementById('myContent');
    var itemcard = `
        <div class="product" id="${id}">
        <div class="product-details">
        <div class="product-title">Dingo Dog Bones</div>
        <p class="product-description"> ${name}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price productprice" >${price}</div>
        <div class="product-quantity">
        <input type="number productquantity" value=${quantity} min="1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-removal">
        <button class="remove-product"> Remove </button>
        </div>
        <div class="product-line-price" id='productlineprice' >25.98</div>
        </div>
                  `;
                itemcontainer.innerHTML += itemcard;
} 
//get this out of the for loop
calculatelinetotal()
```

Now let's fix js code to handle the changes:

```
function calculatelinetotal(){
   //use ByClassName instead of ById
   var pricesList = document.getElementByClassName('productprice').innerHTML;
   var quantitiesList = document.getElementByClassName('productquantity').value;

   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0 ; i < pricesList.length ; i++ ) {
       var price = pricesList[i].value.replace('$','');
       var quantity = quantitiesList[i].value;
       total = price + quantity;
   }
   document.getElementById('productlineprice').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Or change this part:

```
var total = 0;
var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    total += cartarry[i].price.replace('$',"") + cartarry[i].quantity
    //etc......
    document.getElementById('productlineprice').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get different element id by adding array index to id and pass same array index to calculate the line total. Plus it is not a good id to read price from tag because it can be modified by the user. It will be better if you can supply price directly to calculatelinetotal() function.